# Traversing a list in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to make a function that traverses a list,processes the head,stops after K recursions and also creates an identical list using the head element in each recursion.Code:

```
fun trav (0, _, list) = list
  | trav(K, x::xs, list) =
      trav(K - 1, xs, list@[x])
```

so if i call `trav(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6],[])`

I expect

```
  list   =[1]       ,K=3
         =[1,2]     ,K=2
         =[1,2,3]   ,K=1
         =[1,2,3,4] ,K=0
```

However for very large inputs this-> `list@[x]` seems to crash my program(i am not sure why) and if i  use `(x :: list)` instead giving a different (but same sized) list as a result in each step everything works ok.Why is this happening?How could i implement `list@[x]` using the cons operator?

Comment: I don't understand what this function is supposed to do. Surely `list` cannot be equal to `[]`, `[1]`, `[1,2]`, etc. all at once. Could you make the example a bit more clear?

Comment: I am sorry i should not have put in each recursion under the excpected list value.I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

`list@[x]` needs to traverse the entirety of `list`, and then copy it by consing it element by element to `[x]`, which is very inefficient.

The conventional solution is to build the result in reverse, and then reverse it to the desired order when you're done:

```
fun trav (0, _, list) = List.rev list
  | trav (K, x::xs, list) = trav (K-1, xs, x::list)
```

This may seem inefficient, but it is actually much more efficient than the appending version.
(It has linear time complexity rather than quadratic, in case that means anything to you.)

Answer (score 0):

> *[...]* for very large inputs `list@[x]` seems to crash my program *[...]* and if i use `x :: list` instead giving a different (but same sized) list as a result in each step everything works ok.
>
> Why is this happening?

`list@[x]` exhausts your program's [stack memory](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) because the `@` operator is not tail-recursive.

When `list` is very long, it builds an expression like so:

```
   [a,b,c,d,e,f,...] @ z
~> a :: [b,c,d,e,f,g,...] @ z
~> a :: b :: [c,d,e,f,g,...] @ z
~> ...
~> a :: b :: ... :: [] @ z
~> a :: b :: ... :: z :: []
```

All of these intermediary list elements are kept in the recursive call stack, which your program eventually runs out of. And to top this off, this expensive computation is repeated for each element in the list, so a *O(n²)* time cost.